# How to retrieve offset of dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

I am adding elements dynamically using javascipt:

```
$('.marker').append('<div class="container" id="id' + counter + '" ><input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" ></div>');
counter++;
```

And I need to have positions (offset x and y) of those added elements. User can add and delete those elements. Then it should be saved and I need to have final list of elements positions.

I have tried using jquery `offset()` function but it worked only for not dynamically added elements.

Is it possible to retrive offset of those dynamically added elements? And if yes, then how?

Comment: Using `offset` should work fine. See this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XGPt9/3/

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code used to discover the offset for the dynamically created elements. It is definitely possible, as long as those elements are within the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if you're not explaining very well as the following example does what you're asking...

http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/zXSuh/

Just open console and run it.

Here's the code that shows the offset values in the console...

```
$(".container").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).offset().top);
});
```

Comment: Please include the code in your answer, jsfiddle may not always be around, and even now it is taking too long to load to even bother looking at the code.

Comment: It seams that I had my .offset in wrong place in code. Thanks to your fiddle I was able to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = $("<div>", {
    "class": "container",
    id: "id" + counter
}).append($("<input>", {
    type: "text",
    name: "textbox",
    id: "textbox" + counter
}));

$(".marker").append(div);

var offset = div.offset();
console.log(offset.left, offset.top);

counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning a variable to the dynamically created element like so:

```
var el = $('<div class="container" id="id' + counter + '" ><input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" /></div>');

$('.marker').append(el);
counter++;
```

Then you should be able to use el.offset():

```
el.offset();
```